# probability of occurring a moment when the number of black balls is the same as a number of white balls that have been taken out

Tags: probability

There are $m$ white and $n$ black balls in a box, $m>n$. One by one ball is taken out (when taken out it is not returned). What is the probability of occurring a moment when the number of black balls that have been taken out is the same as a number of white balls that have been taken out?

If someone could give me a hint on how to start this problem, I would be very thankful.

Comment: This is a variant of [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).  Note that the complimentary event is that white is ahead in the count the entire way.

Comment: Thank you, so the solution would be $1-\frac{m-n}{m+n}$?

Comment: Yes, that  is correct.